# Why is the photon-sphere around a Kerr Black Hole spherical and not ellipsoid?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

Kerr Black Holes have usually (excluding extrema $a=0$, $a=1$) due to their spinning activity an ellipsoidal ergosphere.

So why does the photon-sphere does not have an ellipsoidal form?

> On the possibility of observation of the future for movement in the field of black holes of different types. Yu.V. Pavlov. [*Gen. Relativ. Gravit.* **45**, 17 (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10714-012-1453-1), [arXiv:1203.4000](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4000).

Comment: Please read our comprehensive paper on photon spheres published in Journal of Mathematical Physics entitled The Geometry of Photon Surfaces, [which is available on the Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0005050). For related areas you might like to look at [this publication list](http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&ln=en&p=find%20a%20Virbhadra&of=hb&action_search=Search&sf=&so=d&rm=&rg=25&sc=0).

Answer (score 1):

> So why does the photon-sphere does not have an ellipsoidal form?

It does have an an ellipsoidal form, or, more exactly, that of an oblated sheroid; in [Boyer Lindquist coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates) where

$${x} = \sqrt {r^2 + a^2} \sin\theta\cos\phi \ , \ \ {y} = \sqrt {r^2 + a^2} \sin\theta\sin\phi \ , \ \ {z} = r \cos\theta$$

the r-coordinate of all the possible photon orbits is constant, but if you transform the pseudospherical coordinate system into the cartesian background space the constant r does indeed transform into an ellipsoid.

For comparison see the [ergospheres and horizons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kerr-surfaces.png) of a rotating black hole in pseudospherical $r, \theta, \phi$ (left, for comparison see Fig. 3 in Nigel Sharp's paper [*"On embeddings of the Kerr geometry"*](https://doi.org/10.1139/p81-086#.WiY8xjeDOHs)) and $x,y,z$ (right, comparison at Fig. 3 in Matt Visser's paper [*"The Kerr spacetime: A brief introduction"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622) ) coordinates:

[image: r,θ,φ and x,y,z coordinates]

While the horizons have a constant $r$ in Boyer Lindquist coordinates, they don't have a constant $R$ in cartesian coordinates. That of course also goes for photon orbits:

[image: ellipsoid photon orbit]

As you can see, the shape of the photon trajectory in cartesian background space is not sperical, but an oblated spheroid. In Fig. 4 of Edward Teo's paper [*"Spherical photon orbits around a Kerr black hole"*](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1026286607562) ([pdf](https://www.physics.nus.edu.sg/~phyteoe/kerr/paper.pdf#page=12)), you can find the same orbit, but in pseudospherical Boyer Lindquist coordinates, where the orbit looks spherical again.

Comment: Please fix the broken links in this post by providing *stable* (DOI) references.

Comment: We do not judge people who use it, but [linking to Sci-Hub is inappropriate here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11142). Similarly, linking to non-stable links is just shooting your answer in the foot, basically ensuring that in one to five years your links will have rotted away. Further, you should *not* link directly to pdfs without explicitly marking them as such, and only when a landing page isn't available.

Comment: I didn't know that, I was linking to the specific pages where the figures I was talking about can be found so the reader would not have to search the whole books

Comment: Then specify the page in the answer text. Linking to pdfs is rather aggressive to users on mobile or lower-speed connections - link to the landing page and they can then decide if they want to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' see much discussion on the linked article about the photon sphere being a true sphere -- they talk about the photon orbit at $r=3M$, but this is only valid for an equatorial orbit (and I'd expect that it would depend on the value of $a$ and you'd have a different radius for corotation and anti-rotation), and when you go away from the equatorial plane, you'll have different values for the orbit.

I'll admit that I"m talking from intuition here, I haven't done the calculation for closed null geodesics in the kerr spacetime.

Short, non-rambly answer: I don't know if the kerr hole even has a photon-sphere in the Schwarzschild case, and if it did, my intuition screams that it will not be a sphere.  (also note, $r=const, t=const$ does not define a sphere in the Kerr spacetime)

Answer (score -3):

Photon "spheres" of Kerr metric are not yet found.  That needs a lot of work. Two  closed photon circles are known.

Comment: This is not true. Edward Teo has a wonderful paper from 2003 on spherical photon orbits around Kerr.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1026286607562